# How do I select the counts of values in a column in pandas for a specific value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns named "column one" and "column two".
I want to select the counts of all values in "column two" where "column one" has value b.
I can do this in two steps with this code:

```
data = [['a', 'val1'], ['b', 'val2'], ['b', 'val2'], ['b','val3'], ['b','val4'], ['a', 'val5'], ['a', 'val6']]
ex = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['column one', 'column two'])
exa = ex[ex['column one']=='b']
exa['column two'].value_counts()
```

This will give me the output:

val2 2

val3 1

val4 1

Now how do I write this such that my output includes the values val1, val5 and val6 showing 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by unique values of original column:

```
s = exa['column two'].value_counts().reindex(ex['column two'].unique(), fill_value=0)
print (s)
val1    0
val2    2
val3    1
val4    1
val5    0
val6    0
Name: column two, dtype: int64
```

> Just out of curiosity is there a way to do this without having to create the second dataframe exa?

Yes, you can chain code together and add [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column by condition:

```
s = (ex.loc[ex['column one']=='b', 'column two']
        .value_counts()
        .reindex(ex['column two'].unique(), fill_value=0))
```

Solution with aggregation:

```
s = ex['column one'].eq('b').view('i1').groupby(ex['column two']).sum()
#alternative
s = ex['column one'].eq('b').astype(int).groupby(ex['column two']).sum()
print (s)
column two
val1    0
val2    2
val3    1
val4    1
val5    0
val6    0
Name: column one, dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
data = [['a', 'val1'], ['b', 'val2'], ['b', 'val2'], ['b','val3'], ['b','val4'], ['a', 'val5'], ['a', 'val6']]
ex = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['column one', 'column two'])
#

ex.groupby('column two')['column one'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x=='b'))
```

This will return a pandas series

Answer (score 0):

duckdb:

```
ex.sql().select("*,case when \"column one\"='b' then 1 else 0 end col1").aggregate("\"column two\",sum(col1) count2")
```

```
┌────────────┬────────┐
│ column two │ count2 │
│  varchar   │ int128 │
├────────────┼────────┤
│ val6       │      0 │
│ val1       │      0 │
│ val2       │      2 │
│ val4       │      1 │
│ val5       │      0 │
│ val3       │      1 │
└────────────┴────────┘
```